# Take(1) from a Select() on a hot observable

Tags: c#, observable, reactive

What I'm trying to do is have a hot observable, and then derive another observable from it through Select.

Next I want to use `await Take(1)` to get a single value from the derived observable and then subsequently subscribe to it.

```
int i = 1;
var o1 = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Select(x => { i++;return i; })
    .Publish()
    .RefCount()
    .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"emit {x}"));

var o2 = o1.Select(x => x + 5);

await o2.Take(1);
Console.ReadLine();

using (o2.Subscribe(x =>
 {
     Console.WriteLine($"output {x}");
 }))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"subscrbied");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

However, what I'm seeing is that after the `await Take(1)`, the observable no longer "works" (no "emit x" is being printed anymore).

Why is this?

**EDIT**

Interestingly, if I add a `Task.Delay` it works:

```
var o2 = o1.Select(x => x + 5);

await o2.Take(1);
await Task.Delay(1);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The combination `.Publish().RefCount()` can be a bit nasty to work with. There are occasions when the subscribers go to zero that the query cannot be resubscribed to.

However, in this case there seems to be a race condition that I've yet to fully figure out.

Here's how to make your code work:

```
await o2.Take(1).ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default);
```

The addition of the `ObserveOn` allows it to operate the way you expect.

Your use of `await Task.Delay(1);` did the same thing. But why is still confusing me.

Finally, ignoring the kludge to make it work, the only reason it appears to work is that you're using the external state `int i = 1;`. You can remove the `.Publish().RefCount()` and it'll still work as expected. You should avoid this kind of external state and if you do use it you should use `Interlocked.Increment(ref i)` instead of `i++`.

---

Based on our discussions, here's an alternative way to get what you need:

```
var subject = new ReplaySubject<long>(1);
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
var subscription = source.Subscribe(subject);
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.5));
var z = await subject.Take(1);
Console.WriteLine($"0:{z}z");
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5));
subject.Take(5).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"1:{x}x"));
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5));
subject.Take(5).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"2:{x}x"));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you said is the case, for example if I use o2.Subscribe twice, I get the expected behavior that the sequence stops when I unsubscribe, but continues when I subscribe again. Also see my edit.

Comment: I just saw your edit re `await Task.Delay(1);` - that's interesting. I think it might be a threading issue or you've found a bug.

Comment: Would the fact that my application is labelled with `[STAThread]` affect anything?
Addressing your second point, yeah I do understand the way external state interacts with the observable chain. The purpose of adding it was for ease of debugging. Without it, the `Publish/Refcount` combination still works, but simply restarts the counting everytime refcount hits 0. Will accept the answer in a few days or if underlying cause is found.

Comment: @sunny-lan - What is your use case here, btw? I'm trying to figure out why you want to do this and whether or not there is a better alternative.

Comment: Not really any deeper use case here, was playing around to see how things actually behave due to lack of documentation. Well I was basically writing an example trying to figure out the interactions between Merge(1), FromAsync(), and a hot observable. If you want to know about the "real" usecase behind it, we can start a chat, as its a bit more complicated.

Comment: @sunny-lan - I'm happy to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233399/discussion-between-sunny-lan-and-enigmativity).